# Access for developers to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to allow developers to access resources on my AWS account.
They will be lunching instances and RDS, possibly some other resources.

What is the best way to achieve this?
IAM roles seem complicated with policies.
Should I lunch instances then give them SSH access?

What are your suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should create an IAM User for each developer. Put them in an IAM Group and assign permissions to the Group.

However, this assumes that you are willing to trust them in your account, for which you should think twice. If you give them permissions to launch services, they might launch more than necessary, causing extra expense. If you give them permission to **delete** resources, they might accidentally delete resources being used by other people.

If they are just "playing around" with AWS to get an idea of what can be done, create a **sandbox account** where they can't do much harm. Keep this separate to your **production account**, where you'll keep resources that you don't want destroyed.

Or, if you just want them to develop software and not play with AWS directly, then do as you suggested and create the resources yourself, but give them access for software development purposes.

**Bottom line:** It all depends on what the developers want to do and what you're willing to let them do.

Answer (score 0):

If it isa small environment, you can give ssh access to developeres.
But the infra is pretty big, then i prefer to go with IAM